# Getting Uncaught Reference Error:Button1_Click is not defined

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, dom-events

Suppose I have an aspx code here:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SearchCustomer.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.eyeofheaven.SearchCustomer" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheets/SearchCustomerStyle.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<title>Search Customer</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="twelve columns">
            <!-- Header-->
            <div class="container">
                <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
                    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Collection of nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                    <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a href="EyeOfHeaven.aspx">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle active" href="#">Search<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="SearchCustomer.aspx">Search Form(Customer)</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="SearchVehicle.aspx">Search Form(Vehicle)</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Search form customer-->
<div id="searchcustomer" class="page-header">
    <h3><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></span>Search Customer</h3>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"><input type="text" size="20" class="form-control" placeholder="Customer ID"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select class="form-control" id="Countries">
                <option>Country</option>
        </select>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select class="form-control" id="Regions">
                <option>Regions</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <button type="button" onclick="Button1_Click()" id="searchinfo" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search Info</button>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Information Table-->
<div class="table-responsive"> 
    <table id="MyTable" class="table table-bordered">
    </table>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And aspx.cs code behind:

```
using MSSQLConnector;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1.eyeofheaven
{
    public partial class SearchCustomer : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Data Not Found.');</script>");
        }
    }
}
```

I want to display an alert('Data not found.') in the search info button. But I get an error in the console:

> "Uncaught Reference Error:Button1_Click is not defined"

I have no idea what makes the code to have an error. Or maybe my alert message is not a valid C# code?  I called the function Button1_Click in this code:

```
<button type="button" onclick="Button1_Click()" id="searchinfo" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search Info</button>
```

Please help I'm new to C# language and I'm adapting the following syntax and its format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your button is not defined at server side. You need to use `runat = "server"` to button and change `onclick` event to `onserverclick` like below

```
<button type="button" id="searchinfo" runat="server" onserverclick="Button1_Click"  class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search Info</button>
```

Instead use [Asp.Net asp:Button control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like below:

```
<asp:Button ID="searchinfo" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" cssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="Search Info"  />
```

Comment: Hello sir thanks for all of you answering my question it definitely work. So it's not advisable to use this code: <button type="button" onclick="Button1_Click()" id="searchinfo" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search Info</button>   for using c# button?

Comment: If you are using asp.net then it's better stick with asp.net controls.

Comment: @laurencekeithalbano you can still access code behind function using `<button />. Please find my updated answer

Comment: @laurencekeithalbano:- There are many advantage which you get while using the asp.net controls like Asp.net controls expose the HTML element of a page in an intuitive object model. Asp.net controls automatically retain the value of their properties by participating in view state. So it is advisable to use it.

Comment: typo sir {onserverclick="Button1_Click()"} I changed it to {onserverclick="Button1_Click"} but it really help me a lot, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make it `asp button` like this

```
<asp:Button onclick="Button1_Click" ID="searchinfo" cssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="Search Info" runat="Server">
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<asp:Button onclick="Button1_Click" ID="searchinfo" 
      cssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="Search Info" runat="Server">
```

ie, define the button to `runat="Server"`. Just to add the `runat` attribute will tell the ASP.Net to parse the element along with its attributes and contents as a server control.