# OnClick Event Inside of Table asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, onclick

I have  been trying to set an OnClick event to my buttons inside of one table.
When the table charge the buttons look good but when I do click nothing happend.

Someone can give me an advice.

CODE

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ObtenerActividadesColaborador();
    }

    public void ObtenerActividadesColaborador()
    {
        LogicaNegocioRequerimiento logicaNegocioRequerimiento = new LogicaNegocioRequerimiento();
        var Actividades = logicaNegocioRequerimiento.ObtenerListaActividadesColaborador("jramireza");
        StringBuilder Builder = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < Actividades.Count; i++)
        {
            Builder.Append("<tr>");
            Builder.Append("<td><asp:Button id='btnActualizar" + i + "' class='btn btn-primary' OnClick='btnActualizar_Click' runat='server' /><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i> Editar</td>");
            Builder.Append("<td><asp:Button id='btnBorrar" + i + "' class='btn btn-danger' OnClick='btnBorrar_Click' runat='server' /><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i> Borrar</td>");
            Builder.Append("<td>" + Actividades[i].IdRequerimiento + "</td>");
            Builder.Append("<td>" + Actividades[i].DscSistema + "</td>");
            Builder.Append("<td>" + Actividades[i].DeRequerimiento + "</td>");
            Builder.Append("<td>" + Actividades[i].CanTiempoAtencion + "</td>");
            Builder.Append("<td>" + Actividades[i].FecRegistroActividad + "</td>");
            Builder.Append("</tr>");
        }
        ListaActividades.InnerHtml = Builder.ToString();
    }

    protected void btnBorrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int c = 1;

    }

    protected void btnActualizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int c = 1;

    }
```

ERROR

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: btnActualizar_Click is not defined
at HTMLUnknownElement.onclick (Actividades:137)
```

Someone know why the event is not working? I tried a lot of forms to do this but I was not lucky.

Tks

Comment: See this topic: [Getting uncaught reference error in a click button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30613724/getting-uncaught-reference-errorbutton1-click-is-not-defined). I hope it helps you!

Comment: See this topic:[Getting uncaught reference error in a click button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30613724/getting-uncaught-reference-errorbutton1-click-is-not-defined) I hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

What do you aim to do with the button click? In its current state, it only creates an integer C and makes its value 1. So every time you click on the button you make an integer C that equals 1, so nothing changes with multiple clicks. Try to do something like creating a public integer C = 1 and

```
protected void btnBorrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int c++;

    }
```

to examine what is going to happen.

Comment: When I wrote  int c = 1; 
It was just to prove that I entered the event, I placed a point of interruption but I never got there

Comment: It is assumed that when I enter the event I would place the correct logic to the event

Comment: The problem is the button not detect the event

Comment: @Alex Did you change the button's name after you generated it in Form.cs? As I remember this happens when an event can't find its object.

Comment: @Alex if you did. You might want to check it by renaming it to its old name. See if it is working.

Comment: The name is asignated dynamically inside the for loop. id='btnActualizar" + i

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the controls to the page before load to bind the events. So you should add the controls in Page_Init event and not Page_Load. Also you would need to handle the postback scenario if your binding events in Page_Load.